# Including the Abstract Class or Polymorphic Class C++

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I've been planning out my lab project for quite some time now as I like to do so before actually jumping into code and have stumbled upon a question I'm not quite sure how to phrase to find the answer online.

I'm currently tasked with writing a very basic text editor in which my professor has given us a basic UI.

What we have to do is ...
- **Create command objects derived from an abstract class**
- **These command objects have an execute and undo method**
- **Each command will control simple actions like adding input, undoing input, or deleting lines**

The question I have is when passing through my commands derived from the abstract class, will I have to import/include each and every command I've derived from the abstract class in order to use like...

```
Command Abstract Class
AddInput Derived Class (from above)

AddInput input = new Command()
```

My ultimate questions is ...

- Will I have to import each and every class I use from the abstract one
- Will doing **Command AddInput = new AddInput()** work the way I think it will work? I know that it's legal in C++, but will it return all the member variables from the AddInput class?

Comment: `import`? What's that?  Do you mean `#include`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I came from a Java background. I meant include.

Comment: *I came from a Java background* -- So that's why you are using `new` like that.  In C++ `Command AddInput;` -- no need for `new`

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for the mixup. Anyways, I'm still a bit confused on the aspect of polymorphism as that's a newly introduced concept for me. I understand how it works, but the exact syntax is a little off for me. If AddInput is derived from Command, will I have to include AddInput.hpp in order to use it? And will I lose any information to splicing? And would the compiler recognize AddInput as a Command type object?

Comment: That's a lot of questions that are best answered by looking at C++ examples.  Second, don't use Java as a model in how to write C++ code.  You'll end up with awful code that is full of memory leaks and just plain looks weird.

Comment: I understand. I've been transitioning over, but I have been using delete to get rid of any potential memory leaks. My professor is requiring that we pass pointers to command objects.

Comment: How every C++ programmer wished that just issuing `delete` gets rid of memory leaks that easily.  That's why C++ has smart pointers -- it isn't as easy as you think it is.  And yes, you should `#include` the header of a class you intend to use in your source module.  Unlike Java's `import`, `#include` is much simpler -- it is literally a "copy / paste" of the file at the location where the #include appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if `Command` is an abstract class (or interface if you like), you could not create an instance of it, so code `Command cmd = ...` is incorrect. You could use only pointer to it. Lets consider some simple example:

```
//cmdintfs.h 
class ICommand
{
public:
  virtual bool Execute() = 0;
  virtual bool Undo() = 0;
  virtual ~ICommand() {};
};

#include "cmdintfs.h"
class CDoSmthCommand : public ICommand
{
public: //some cmd implementation
};

class CDoOtherThingsCommand : public ICommand
{
public: //some cmd implementation
};

//...
ICommand *pCmd = new CDoOtherThingsCommand();
pCmd->Execute();
```

Here we have an interface `ICommand` and some derived implementations. `ICommand` is declared in the `cmdintfs.h` and all command realization sources should include that header. When you are using your commands through the polymorphic `ICommand` interface, you will have access only to methods, which it describes (`Execute` and `Undo` in our example). All other specific implementation will be hidden.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough and informative response! If the constructor for the abstract class has an " = default " at the end, will my derived classes be forced to use that default constructor?

Comment: You could freely override object constructors on any layer of the class hierarchy. You will have to provide code for the correct constructors chain calls although.

Comment: Thank you, I got everything sorted out. You were a great help.